# How does one move the taskbar to the secondary monitor in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, taskbar

I'm running windows 10 and have two monitors. I'd like to have my task bar appear only on my secondary monitor. Let me be clear, I am **NOT** asking how to switch the primacy of my monitors, because I know how to do that; I'm asking how to split the two tasks ("New program launching" and "task bar having") which are both assigned to the primary display between two monitor.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.actualtools.com/multiplemonitors/

This looks like it might be what you're looking for.  It says it lets you set specific rules for which monitor programs open on, and it allows you to extend the task bar (though I'm not sure it lets you put it on only the second)

Edit:

I have not tried this, and am not 100% sure it will work on windows 10